# Theorem/Definition/Lemma problem — Numbering in Beamer

Tags: beamer, numbering, theorems

I am trying to work on the numbering of the theorems/definitions/lemmas etc., and I have some problems with the numbering.

I would like the theorems, propositions, corollarys, definitions, examples in Beamer (a presentation) as follows:

> 1 Functions (SECTION)
>
> 1.1 Basics (SUBSECTION)
>
> Definition 1.1.1.
>
> Theorem 1.1.1.
>
> Theorem 1.1.2.
>
> Example 1.1.1.
>
> 1.2 Some result (SUBSECTION)
>
> Definition 1.2.1.
>
> Theorem 1.2.1.
>
> Theorem 1.2.2.
>
> Example 1.2.1.

Comment: `\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]`

Comment: I got Theorem 1.1.
      Theorem 1.2.

Comment: Ow, there is no `chapter`. So use `subsection` instead.

Comment: I already use subsection but I got Theorem 0.1. Theorem 0.2. It is not Theorem 1.1.1.   Theorem 1.1.2.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Your attendants will suffer with that numbering schema. At least, make all structures to share a counter.

Comment: Doesn't my answer solve your question?

Answer (score 10):

You need to number subsections within sections and theorems within sections, to achieve what you want.

```
\numberwithin{subsection}{section}
\numberwithin{theorem}{subsection}
```

Also, you need to declare

```
\setbeamertemplate{theorems}[numbered]
```

otherwise they are not numbered at all.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{theorems}[numbered]
\numberwithin{subsection}{section}
\numberwithin{theorem}{subsection}

\begin{document}
\section{Functions}
\subsection{Basics}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{A Theorem on Infinite Sets}
\begin{theorem}
There exists an infinite set.
\end{theorem}
\begin{proof}
This follows from the axiom of infinity.
\end{proof}
\begin{example}[Natural Numbers]
The set of natural numbers is infinite.
\end{example}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that I haven't changed the fact that all theorem-like environments share the same counter.