# Label blocks inlcuding section number

Tags: beamer, cross-referencing, numbering

I want to add section number when referencing blocks. MWE is as follows:

```
\documentclass[serif,12pt,xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid} 
\usepackage{lipsum}  
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Example \ref{block1}}
\section{}
\begin{block}{}\label{block1}
\lipsum[2]
\end{block}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

This is what I have at the moment:

[image]

But I would like to have the following:

[image]

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Try `\documentclass[serif,12pt,xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid} 
\usepackage{lipsum}  
\begin{document}
\section{A section}
\begin{frame}{Example \arabic{section}.\ref{block1}}
\begin{block}{}\label{block1}
\lipsum[2]
\end{block}
\end{frame}
\end{document}`

Comment: Many thanks @marmot, it works! I was wondering if there is a way to automatically include section number without having to type the section number in front of `\ref{block1}` every time.

Comment: Of course, there is e.g. the `\numberwithin` command that AFAIK comes with amsmath. That is, you need to declare your example to be a "theorem-like" environment that and then say  `\numberwithin{example}{section}`. I guess a reasonable starting point would be [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/229727/121799) and say `\numberwithin{theorem}{section}` instead. Of course, it will be better to wait till @samcarter sees this question and gives a real answer. ;-)

Comment: I think the main problem is that blocks are not numbered and if you label them, you will get the framenumber. So your document above only works by chance. I'll see if I can add counters to the blocks.

Comment: In case this does not work, you could define a new type of block with `\newtheorem` - numbering for theorems can be enabled and they can be numbered within the section

Comment: @marmot For someone who claims that his crystal ball is missing, you are remarkably good at predicting the future... :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is actually more tricky than you make it look. The main problem is that blocks are not numbered in beamer and if you label them, you will get the framenumber and not the number of the block.

You can modify the definition of the block environment to include a counter. Once blocks are numbered you can use @marmots great suggestion and use `\numberwithin{block}{section}` to include the section number.

Additional comment: never ever use `\section` inside a frame, this can have serve side-effects.

```
\documentclass[12pt,xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}
\usefonttheme{serif}
\usetheme{Madrid} 
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcounter{block}
\setcounter{block}{0}
\numberwithin{block}{section}

\setbeamertemplate{block begin}
{%
    \refstepcounter{block}%
  \par\vskip\medskipamount%
  \begin{beamerboxesrounded}[upper=block title,lower=block body,shadow=true]%
    {\raggedright\usebeamerfont*{block title}\insertblocktitle}%
    \raggedright%
    \usebeamerfont{block body}%
}

\begin{document}

\section{}
\begin{frame}{Example \ref{block1}}
\begin{block}{}\label{block1}
\lipsum[2]
\end{block}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
content...
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Example \ref{block2}}
\begin{block}{}\label{block2}
\lipsum[2]
\end{block}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow, many thanks @samcarter! This is exactly what I had in mind! That's amazing!

Comment: @Alex You're welcome!